# Should I use ComponentDidMount or mergeProps of connect function for data fetching?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I use react with redux and have a component which displays some dataSet fetched from external source. My current code looks like:

```js
const ConnectedComponent = connect(
  state => ({
    dataSet: state.dataSet
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    loadData: () => {
      ...
      fetch data and dispatch it to the store
      ...
    }
  })
)(MyComponent); 

class MyComponent extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dataSet, loadData } = this.props;
    if (!dataSet) {
      loadData();
    }
  } 
  ... 
  render () {
    const { dataSet } = this.props;
    if (dataSet) {
      // render grid with data
    } else {
      // render Loading...
    }
  }
}
```

The code above works but I'm wondering would it be better to get rid of **componentDidMount** and just check for data and load it from within **connect** function? The code might looks like:

```js
const ConnectedComponent = connect(
  state => ({
    dataSet: state.dataSet
  }),
  dispatch => ({ 
    dispatch 
  }),
  (stateProps, dispatchProps) => {
    const { dataSet } = stateProps;
    const { dispatch } = dispatchProps;

    if (!dataSet) {
      // fetch data asynchronously and dispatch it to the store
    } 

    return {
      ...stateProps
    };
  }
)(MyComponent); 

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render () {
    const { dataSet } = this.props;
    if (dataSet) {
      // render grid with data
    } else {
      // render Loading...
    }
  }
}
```

The latter code looks more attractive to me because of **MyComponent** becomes simpler. There is no passing of execution first forward from connected component to presentational and then backward, when **componentDidMount** detects that there are no data ready to display.

Are there some drawbacks of such approach?

PS: I use redux-thunk for an asynchronous fetching.

Comment: I believe the second snippet abuses Redux. Side effects are supposed to go to a middleware. You could do the same thing with a thunk but with less issues regarding testability, extensibility, etc.

Comment: I'm using redux-thunk. The question is should I detect missing data from within component or at connect HOC level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach, as **separation of concepts**, is potentially a good solution, because of the layers and responsibility separations - `ConnectedComponent` is responsible for data fetching, while `MyComponent` acts as presentational component. Good!

But, dispatching actions in connect `mergeProps` doesn't seem a good idea, because you introduce **side effects**.

Also, other drawback I'm seeing, is that the flow of fetching and returning data would be repeated across your different pages (components). Generally speaking the following flow would be repeated:

1. Connected components call the API for the needed Entities.
2. While fetching the Entities, we’re showing a Loader.
3. When the data is available, we pass it to the Presentational components.

---

Because of the above drawbacks, I can suggest you to organize and reuse your data fetching flow in a **HOC**.

Here's a pseudo code and flow (taken from my article) that addresses the above drawbacks:

* *I've been using it last 1 year and continue stick with it.*

**Fetcher HOC:**

```
import authorActions from 'actions/author'

const actions = {
  'Author': authorActions
}

export default (WrappedComponent, entities) => {

  class Fetcher extends React.Component {
    // #1. Calls the API for the needed Entities.
    componentDidMount () {
      this.fetch()
    }

    fetch () {
      const { dispatch } = this.props

      entities.forEach(name => dispatch(actions[name].get()))
    }

    render () {
      const { isFetching } = this.props

      // #2. While fetching the Entities, we're showing an Loader.
      if (isFetching) return <Loader />

      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const isFetching =  entities
      .map(entity => state[entity].isFetching)
      .filter(isFetching => isFetching)

    return { isFetching: isFetching.length > 0 }
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Fetcher)
}
```

**Usage:**

```
const MyComponent = ({ authors }) => <AuthorsList authors={authors} />

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authors: state.authors
})

const Component = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
export default Fetcher(Component, ['Author'])
```

Here you can read the article and deep dive into its ideas and concepts:

* *Fetcher concept is addressed at **Lesson #2: Containers on steroids***

[**Long-term React & Redux SPA — Lessons learned**](https://notes.devlabs.bg/long-term-react-redux-spa-lessons-learned-14daca3a26ba)